# How to parse C# code to find the derived class and interfaces of a class

Tags: c#, regex, parsing

I am looking for an approach for finding the code between the base class identifier colon and the opening curly brace of a class that's been that's been stored into a string literal.

By this I mean that I have a class

```
public class Class : BaseClass
{    
}
```

That's been stored as a string

```
string classString = "public class Class : BaseClass{}\r\n"
```

The class will most certainly be more detailed with the potential for strongly-typed, fully qualified base class and interfaces, but I need an approach for sniffing out the code between the colon and opening curly bracket.

Assuming that the class is not a generic that defines derivation constraint
  i.e.

```
public class LinkedList<K,T> : BaseClass
  **where K : IComparable**
{
}
```

Then it might be safe to assume that there would on be one colon in the class definition and it would fairly easy to find the derivation colon and the opening curly brace.

If that's the case I could do

```
    string baseClassString = classString.Substring(derivationColonIndex + 1, (openCurlyBraceIndex - (derivationColonIndex + 1)))
```

Can anyone think of a better approach that would GUARANTEE the I get a string for the baseClass and any interfaces that might exist between the colon and opening curly brace.

Background for why I'm needing this : Classes are being generated base on data coming from a database, if the certain data in the db changes, then potentially, I have the need to change the inheritance in the class string. Thus, I would replace the existing substring of the base class and interfaces.

Comment: Wow, that sounds like a really bad idea, man. And I agree with Stefan, this is a job for RegEx, if you're not going to use reflection. Godpspeed.

Comment: What constraints are on the text in the string? Is it guaranteed to be valid C#? Can it contain comments? Can it contain "preprocessor" directives? Multiple type declarations? Nested type declarations? Attributes?

Comment: All are very valid points. Stefan - a lot of times I have solved the problem on my own before someone responds with a viable solution. I've had questions answered 1+ years after asking, and may have overlooked giving someone the credit that they probably deserver. I understand this is a community that gives people rep and kudos for being brainy programmers and allows them to be able to toot their own horns at times, and while I'm not really here for that, I will try harder.

Comment: As for RegEx, I was hoping not to go down that path due to the fact that every time I encounter the need to use RegEx I literally have to re-learn it, but I guess that's what I may have to do.

Comment: Eric - There are most likely not going to be any constraints. The code is guaranteed to be valid c# because it has been generated. No comments or preprocessor directives. It will, almost in every case, just inherit some parent class. I was hoping that this was simple enough not to have to deal w/ regex or anything too tricky.

Answer (score 5):

Man, you really should be using CodeDOM:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y2k85ax6.aspx

> The CodeDOM provides types that
>   represent many common types of source
>   code elements. You can design a
>   program that builds a source code
>   model using CodeDOM elements to
>   assemble an **object graph**. This object
>   graph can be rendered as source code
>   using a CodeDOM code generator for a
>   supported programming language. The
>   CodeDOM can also be used to compile
>   source code into a binary assembly.

I'd like to draw your attention to the object graph.  Using the object graph, you should be able to do what you need to do.

EDIT:  Sorry for the misdirection, actually what you're trying to accomplish is the reverse of what I suggested - my bad!  You may want to look at the following projects, which offer the capability to **build an object graph** from the code, rather than generate code from an object graph:

http://csparser.codeplex.com/

http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/Default.aspx?Page=NRefactory&NS=&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1

Comment: This is pretty cool. I had never heard of this. It might be difficult to adapt it for the use we need but it is definately something that I will keep in mind for future use. Thanks.

Comment: How does this help if you're *starting* with the string? The problem as I understand it is that there is a string which must be understood as a graph. CodeDOM goes the other way: it turns the graph into the string.

Comment: @Eric, you're right... man, I was on a weird tangent yesterday.  Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 2):

You are going down into a pretty deep rabbit hole.  Writing your own C# language parser is a task that can keep you occupied for a long time, with a pay-off that enhances your skill as a programmer but doesn't turn the boss' frown upside-down.

You are re-inventing a wheel.  The DataSet designer built into Visual Studio already does what you're trying to do.  It could be argued that it is the wrong wheel, the fans of NHibernate will certainly think so.  They generate the dbase schema from the C# class declarations.

Rescue your plan by considering that *modifying* an existing C# class that models the dbase is not necessary.  Just re-generate the class from scratch every time you compile.  It normally only takes a fraction of a second.  The compiler will dutifully warn you when there's a breaking change.  That's how the Settings designer and the Resource designer work.

Comment: Essentially we have a schema importing utility that will import the necessary schema information of any of our databases. We then have a code generator that generates data objects from the information in the database. Without getting too detailed, the code generator has the ability to completely overwrite the data objects at anytime with 100% accuracy every time. The issues is coming from the fact that an app developer can add "custom/additional" code to the data objects.

Comment: The code generator detects this, and knows that it will need to merge the code instead of overwriting it so that the custom code is not lost. That's where the current issue is coming from. This process is not nearly perfect, and has been around for a while, and we do not have the option to start from scratch.  Besides the ability to "Re-Parent" a class, our code generator works exactly as we need it to. Considering this is just an in-house tool, we have more important things to invest our time into. Thanks you all for your replies. It is all very useful information.

Comment: Devs should extend the auto-generated classes by inheriting from them.

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to spend some time learning it, SharpDevelop contains a C# parser named [NRefactory](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/Default.aspx?Page=NRefactory&NS=&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1). It returns an abstract syntax tree from a source string. It could catch errors and handle other language elements like comments, attributes, etc.

Obviously it's not a quick fix, but if you have the time it's an interesting tool.

Answer (score 0):

There's an [ANTLR grammar for C#](http://antlrcsharp.codeplex.com/). Maybe you can use that?